# Immutable Trie in Pure C

Tags: c, trie, persistent

Is there an implementation of persistent data structures in pure C, without using C++?

Im thinking about the sort of data structure as implemented in most functional languages.

More info: https://sched.co/A8J0

Comment: There is nothing you can implement in C++ that you cannot implement in C, too.  But there is no such data structure included in the C standard library, and if you're asking for a pre-built implementation then that's off-topic here.

Comment: That there is nothing in the standard answers my question.